# Adding a month to a date changes the timezone from GMT to BST

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone

Got a weird issue of timezones changing when adding units of times to dates in JavaScript. How do I prevent this behaviour?

[image]
It is not currently BST where I am... still GMT.

Update: This bug is not apparently reproducible outside the UK.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that whatever your local time zone is, it observes daylight savings switching between GMT and BST. [British Summer Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Summer_Time) begins on the last Sunday in March, so when you add a month to a March date (that is in GMT in your time zone), you get an April date that is in BST in your time zone.

To illustrate what I mean, try creating a JavaScript date object for February 1, 2019 similar to the example in your question (but replacing March with February), then add a month to the date and you should see that the output date is still displayed in GMT on your local machine because BST doesn't begin until the end of March.